# How use MS SQL as primary database in Bonita 6

Tags: sql-server, database, tomcat, business-process-management

Good day. :D

I'm in some trouble configuring BonitaBPM with Ms Sql database.

Already searched a lot on the internet but many of the examples used in mysql show, it tried to do the same, so that the problem that the files mentioned in the articles do not exist in my folders setup Bonita (Bundle, etc.).

I try to configure the file that  links to BD's but gives a runtime error.

My goal is to use Ms Sql as the primary database, thus making the emigration of all tables in Bonita to SQL DB.

I would like to receive an example how to do this configuration.

Thank you already.

Comment: Could you please add the runtime error ? And do you want to use MS SQL with Bonita Studio, or a production Bundle ?

Comment: I want to use A production Bundle (Tomcat). I folow this steps to configure, i created a database, removed the H2 listener,
I edite specify the database vendor (sqlserver), did the configuration for lock management and last 
Configure the datasources but nothing working.

Comment: PS: I am using Ms Sql 2012

Comment: With SQL 2008 it is an easy setup. If you are in a testing phase, could please use this version? It should work with 2012 too, but it is more complicated because of changes between the two versions, and so it needs expertise.

Comment: Hey i tried with SQL 2008 but no sucess is giving some problems with the connector (Database vendor).

Comment: Reading your last comment, I will clarify basics. Bonita BPM Studio is using H2 db, is for development only. For production, you can use Bundles (Tomcat, Jboss, or Deploy), and set the database you want. Connectors are not for main database, but for processes connection to other information systems (database, crm, erp, ...) So, what is your need ?

Comment: Ps: I've tried to change and use other connectors, I started using Microsoft's own sqljdbc_3.0 and 4.0 and then moved to JTDS driver but none works. What do you recommend to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Bonita BPM 6 can be configured to use Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (Bonitasoft provide official support for such configuration) but only with the JBoss bundle or other supported applications server such as Oracle WebLogic.

That is because:

- Apache Tomcat is not a full Java EE application server
- An extra library (Bitronix) is included to provide transaction management support
- Bitronix has [known issues](http://bitronix-transaction-manager.10986.n7.nabble.com/Failed-to-recover-SQL-Server-Restart-td148.html) with SQL Server

So only solution I may suggest is to switch to JBoss bundle, or, if possible, use an alternative DBMS such as PostgreSQL.

Sorry to not be able to come with a better option but here we facing a limitation of Bitronix library.

Comment: I know the question is not about this, but could you help me to display the result of a select in the PostgreSQL database in the Bonitasoft 7 UI Designer, or else help me with my question here from Stack?